# Search and replace (escape) double quotes within double quotes in CSV values

Tags: regex, csv, sed, regexp-replace

I want to replace all occurencies of `"` between `,"` and `",` with `'''` (three singular quotes). It will be done on a csv file and on all possible nested quotes to not mess up formatting.
E.g.
`"test","""","test"` becomes
`"test","''''''","test"`.
Another example:
`"test","quotes "inside" quotes","test"`
becomes
`"test","quotes '''inside''' quotes"`.

I use https://sed.js.org/ to test the replacement.

What I currently have is

```
sed "s/\([^,]\)\(\"\)\(.\)/\\1'\\''\\3/g"
```

but it seems not completed and it doesn't cover all cases that I want.

e.g.
works:
`"anything","inside "quotes"","anything"` ->
`"anything","inside '''quotes'''","anything"`
doesn't work for:
`"anything","inside "test" quotes","anything"` ->
`"anything''',"inside '''test''' quotes''',"anything"`
expected ->
`"anything","inside '''test''' quotes","anything"`

Maybe somebody is good with regex expressions and could help?

Comment: This is not *standard* CSV, regarding [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-archive.org/getrfc.php?rfc=4180): **If double-quotes are used to enclose fields, then a double-quote
       appearing inside a field must be escaped by preceding it with
       another double quote**

Comment: Then for working with CSV file, use CSV libraries!

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ cat input_file
"test","""","test"
"test","quotes "inside" quotes","test"
"anything","inside "quotes"","anything"
"anything","inside "test" quotes","anything"

$ sed -E ':a;s/(,"[^,]*('"'"'+)?)"([^,]*"(,|$))/\1'"'''"'\3/;ta' input_file
"test","''''''","test"
"test","quotes '''inside''' quotes","test"
"anything","inside '''quotes'''","anything"
"anything","inside '''test''' quotes","anything"
```

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the triple single quotes is avoided woth a variable `${qs}`.
Start replacing all quotes with `${qs}`.
Next reset the replacements at the start of line, end of line and around `,`.

```
qs="'''"
sed "s/\"/${qs}/g; s/^${qs}/\"/; s/${qs}$/\"/; s/${qs},${qs}/\",\"/g" csvfile
```